# Why does this trick to derive the formula for $[A^n,B]$ in terms of repeated commutators work so well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

It is a known result that, given generically noncommuting operators $A,B$, we have
$$ A^n B=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \operatorname{ad}^k(A)(B) A^{n-k},\tag A $$
where $\operatorname{ad}^k(A)(B)\equiv[\underbrace{A,[A,[\dots,[A}_k,B]\dots]] $.

This can be proved for example via induction with not too much work.

However, while trying to get a better understanding of this formula, I realised that there is a much easier way to derive it, at least on a formal, intuitive level.

#### The trick

Let $\hat{\mathcal S}$ and $\hat{\mathcal C}$ (standing for "shift" and "commute", respectively) denote operators that act on expressions of the form $A^k D^j A^\ell$ (denoting for simplicity $D^j\equiv\operatorname{ad}^j(A)(B)$) as follows:

\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal S} (A^k D^j A^\ell) 
&= A^{k-1} D^j A^{\ell+1}, \\
\hat{\mathcal C} (A^{k} D^{j} A^\ell)
&= A^{k-1} D^{j+1} A^{\ell}.
\end{align}
In other words, $\hat{\mathcal S}$ "moves" the central $D$ block on the left, while $\hat{\mathcal C}$ makes it "eat" the neighboring $A$ factor.

It is not hard to see that $\hat{\mathcal S}+\hat{\mathcal C}=\mathbb 1$, which is but another way to state the identity
$$A[A,B]=[A,B]A+[A,[A,B]].$$
Moreover, crucially, $\hat{\mathcal S}$ and $\hat{\mathcal C}$ commute.
Because of this, I can write

$$A^n B=(\hat{\mathcal S}+\hat{\mathcal C})^n (A^n B)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \hat{\mathcal S}^{n-k} \hat{\mathcal C}^{k}(A^n B),$$
which immediately gives me **(A)** without any need for recursion or other tricks.

#### The question

Now, this is all fine and dandy, but it leaves me wondering as to *why does this kind of thing work*?
It looks like I am somehow bypassing the nuisance of having to deal with non-commuting operations by switching to a space of "superoperators", in which the same operation can be expressed in terms of *commuting* "superoperators".

I am not even sure how one could go in formalising this "superoperators" $\hat{\mathcal S},\hat{\mathcal C}$, as they seem to be objects acting on "strings of operators" more than on the elements of the operator algebra themselves.

Is there a way to formalise this way of handling the expressions? Is this a well-known method in this context (I had never seen it but I am not well-versed in this kinds of manipulations)?

Comment: First note that your trick does use recursion, in the proof of the binomial theorem, so you didn't actually get rid of the recursion, only pushed it further away from sight. Secondly, I don't know how general you're trying to see things, but your trick can probably be formalized using some free noncommutative algebra on $A,B,D$

Comment: @Max yes ok, I didn't mean to say that I wanted a way to completely get rid of recursion for its own sake, the point was more about having a more direct way to get to the result (but also, do you really need recursion to prove the binomial theorem? I would have said that a combinatorial argument is more than sufficient for that. Then again, recursion might be used for the combinatorial formulas I guess). I am not familiar with "free algebras", but from a quick read on wikipedia it seems to be kind of a way to formalize acting on strings of "formal objects", so it seems on point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix some notation, suppose that the operators $A$ and $B$ belong to a vector space $V$, and that we are working with strings of $m$ operators. (For example, in $A^k D^j A^l$ we have $m = k + j + l$). Rather than writing a product $A^k B^j$ as an element of $V$, we can instead write
$$ A^{\otimes k} \otimes B^{\otimes j} = \underbrace{A \otimes \cdots \otimes A}_k \otimes \underbrace{B \otimes \cdots \otimes B}_j \in V^{\otimes m}$$
an element of the $m$th tensor power of $V$. We have a linear multiplication map $\mu: V^{\otimes m} \to V$, which is just composition of operators, so for example $\mu(A^{\otimes k} \otimes B^{\otimes j}) = A^k B^j$. So the idea will be to define $\hat{\mathcal{S}}$ and $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ as linear operators $V^{\otimes m} \to V^{\otimes m}$, check that they commute and add to give the identity, and then finally apply them to a particular tensor $A^{\otimes n} \otimes B$, which will give an identity much like the one you're after. Applying the multiplication $\mu$ will then give the exact identity.

Defining the operators is not too hard. We can take $\hat{\mathcal{S}}, \hat{\mathcal{C}} : V^{\otimes m} \to V^{\otimes m}$ to be defined by the formulas
$$ \begin{aligned}
\hat{\mathcal{S}}(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m) &= v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m \otimes v_1 \\
\hat{\mathcal{C}}(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m) &= v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m - v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m \otimes v_1 \end{aligned}$$
We then check that these formulas do the right thing, for example we need to make sure that $\mu(\hat{\mathcal{C}}^k (A^{\otimes m-1} \otimes B)) = A^{m-k-1} D^k$ and so on.

With those definitions, it is easy to see that $\hat{\mathcal{C}} = \mathbb{1} - \hat{\mathcal{S}}$, and so they also commute, since $\hat{\mathcal{C}}\hat{\mathcal{S}} = \hat{\mathcal{S}}\hat{\mathcal{C}} = \hat{\mathcal{S}} - \hat{\mathcal{S}}^2$. So we can write
$$ A^{\otimes n} \otimes B = (\hat{\mathcal{S}} + \hat{\mathcal{C}})^n (A^{\otimes n} \otimes B) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (\hat{\mathcal{S}}^{n-k} \hat{\mathcal{C}}^k) (A^{\otimes n} \otimes B)$$
and finally applying $\mu$ on both sides gives the formula you are after.

Comment: very nice, I didn't realize you could so simply define the operators via "rotations" of the character strings. Still I wonder, is there any kind of generality in this sort of approach to derive formulas? For example, I realised that one can also easily derive the explicit formula for the repeated commutator $\operatorname{ad}^k(A)B$ as $\operatorname{ad}^k(A)B=(A_L-A_R)^k B$, where $A_L, A_R$ denote "multiplication by A on the left/right". This trick can be similarly understood as operators in the tensor algebra of $V$. I wonder if something similar could work to derive, say, the BCH formula

Comment: I guess something swept under the rug in this answer was that you could actually define those operators on the tensor power. (It wasn’t obvious to me that I could make up a $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ which lifted yours). Also, the fact that everything was an operator on the same tensor power. If you have to move between different tensor powers, things become a little more complicated and there is more to check. But as you say, using the tensor algebra would be the right replacement.